# Javascript slider add/remove function that doesn't remove first slide

Tags: javascript, html

I've looked at this site for a couple of years but only now have encountered a problem that couldn't be solved via reading the answers of others.

I feel like my problem is a simple one to overcome, but I'm having a block on it for some reason.

I have a 'slick' slider that adds and removes slides, in the future I hope to make it so that the first slide is an undeletable upload form. Each upload will then generate a new slide. Deleting that upload will remove that specific slide.

My first issue is that I'm not exactly sure how to make the first slide undeletable...If being hung up on this problem means I won't be able to tackle creating what I mentioned above, there may be *cough cough* paid work for someone who can pull it off. (Sorry if it's against the rules to say that)

Here is my code, hopefully it's all you need:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.add-remove').slick({
      dots: true,
      slidesToShow: 1,
      speed: 500,
      slidesToScroll: 1
  });
  var slideIndex = 1;
  $('.js-add-slide').on('click', function() {
      slideIndex++;
      $('.add-remove').slick('slickAdd','<div><h3>' + slideIndex + '</h3></div>');
  });

  $('.js-remove-slide').on('click', function() {
      $('.add-remove').slick('slickRemove', slideIndex - 1);
      if (slideIndex !== 0){
          slideIndex--;
      }
  });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

What you call `slideIndex` is not the index, but the number of slides. This means you are always removing the last slide. `slideCount` would be a more suitable name. To restrict deletion and to just delete the active element you can do this:

```
var slideCount = 0, slideSequence = 0;

$('.js-remove-slide').on('click', function() {
    var slideIndex = $('.slick-slide.slick-active').data('slick-index');
    if (slideIndex != 0){
        $('.add-remove').slick('slickRemove', slideIndex);
        slideCount--;
    }
});

$('.js-add-slide').on('click', function() {
    slideCount++;
    $('.add-remove').slick('slickAdd','<div><h3>' + slideSequence + '</h3></div>');
    slideSequence++;
});
```

The add will add a new slide in the end probably, this depends on the implementation of `slickAdd` and it will always get the next number, even if something was deleted, to show where something was deleted and created.

Comment: this looks right - I missed that slideIndex was being incremented and not the actual index value of the slide

Comment: Thanks. You can have his job, I don't have the time ;-)

Comment: Thanks for that answer! Does that work for you? Because for me it won't work if I create more than one slide.

Comment: @maraca Thanks very much for your help but I'm still having the same issue with deleting multiple slides. Even if I make a slide the active one and hit 'remove', it stays there.  I updated the link in the original question with your code if you want to see what I mean. Just add 4 or 5 slides in one go and try to go to each and delete them.

Comment: @OisinMc you have some cloned slicks in there I don't know if that is correct. And could it be that the remove doesn't work correctly, you can check by putting alert(slideIndex) to see if you get the correct index for removal

Comment: @OisinMc anyway for me it seems to work, tried to refresh or clear cache of browser?

Comment: @maraca Yup, tried those things and tried it in a different browser. I just created 4 slides at the same time, click slide 1 and delete it which works fine. Click slide 2 and click remove which removes slide 3. Clicking remove on any of the other ones doesn't do anything. Do you mean that when you click each slide and click delete it does it no problem? Even if you were to create 5 slides?

Comment: @OisinMc I think the index gets mixed up, have you removed old occurences of slideIndex? and replaced by slideCount where needed?

Comment: @OisinMc Just saw that active is not set correctly after removal, you have to set active manually to slideIndex or slideIndex-1 if it was the last slide (slideIndex === slideCount-1). probably there is a function to scroll to slide X, just call that after removal and you're done

Answer (score 1):

In this case I would check for the length of slices and would only delete if the length is greater than 1.

Something like this should work

```
if ($(".slick-slide").length > 1) {
    // deletion code
}
```